# Corda check session.send/receive completeness

Tags: blockchain, corda, corda-flow

I am currently creating some custom flows, sending back and forth some data through the session. I noticed that in some cases (for example if a responder flow has a session.receive still unanswered when the initiating flow finishes), no exceptions are thrown and everything works smoothly, without even a warn log. Is there a way to force the check of send/receive completeness?

Answer (score 0):

If you can provide some log file to demonstrate your use case would be better.

Send & Receive is typically a one-direction communication, one sends and one receives. If you are looking for a confirm receive, you can try to use method sendAndReceive, which

```
Serializes and queues the given payload object for sending to the counterparty.
Suspends until a response is received, which must be of the given R type.
```

Receive method itself is a blocking method, so if your flow successfully finishes. it means the receive method successfully receive what it is looking for.

But again, it would be much better if you can share your log and the elaborate on your questions a bit.

Comment: There isn't any log or warning, that's the issue! The only way to reproduce it, is the following: create an initiating flow which sends some data and waits to receive some other data. Create a receiver flow which receive this data and sends back an answer, **and then waits to receive some other data**, which we know it will never comes (we intentionally create the bug). At this point the initiator has again the control of the flow, and he completes, and calls receiverSession.close

Comment: The problem is that no warnings or exceptions are thrown by the recevierSession.close method, because we actually have a bug in our code (one receive call is not answered in the responder flow), and we don't know it! It looks everything is working perfectly, but it's not

Comment: It would be nice for a framework like Corda, to be 100% sure that when the initiator flow completes, also all the responders have completed successfully, and not that they are stuck somewhere..